# Rx java: emits first item, ignore coming items for 5 seconds

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following case:

- The user clicks refresh button multiple times.
- I want to process just one click, ignore other clicks for 5 seconds.
- Process another new click that comes after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rxjava2, You can use:

```
.throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

From the [javadoc documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleFirst-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> **throttleFirst**:
>   Returns an Observable that emits only the first item emitted by the source ObservableSource during sequential time windows of a specified duration.

Answer (score 0):

in [Rxjava 2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), you should use [debounce](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#debounce-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) operator which emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item

```
.debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: But in `debounce` you will not instantly respond to the first user input. You will wait 300ms to react to the user input. while in `.throttleFirst` you respond instantly to the first user input.